# Keywords em paginações

Tags: php, javascript, html

Como eu posso inserir as *keywords* e até mesmo o título da minha página nessas "Páginas que não existem".

Por exemplo, eu fiz uma paginação e minha *url* muda conforme eu mudo o valor da `url/conteúdo`, o titulo e outras *keywords* continuam com o mesmo valor da página principal.

Eu uso o cabeçalho da minha `index.php` para minhas outras páginas, como `conteudo.php`, `sobre.php` etc..

O título da minha `index.php` é *home*, mas o título do arquivo `conteudo.php` teria q ser outro, mas o título também é *home*.

Devo criar cabeçalhos para arquivos diferentes ou existe alguma forma de trocar o título da página sem precisar criar outro cabeçalho ?

> Existem alguns métodos para mudar o título via Javascript, mas os que eu usei sempre deixavam o título original da página no *head* que é o lugar certo e o título do conteúdo na `body` no meio de alum conteúdo.  Então optei por não usar dessa maneira.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui tem uma técnica que pode ser interessante também.

O que vc tem que fazer é *executar a lógica dos títulos antes do html*, veja abaixo.

```
<?php
//index.php
//aqui vem a lógica php antes do html carregar

$page = isset($_GET['menu'])?$_GET['menu']:'home';

switch($page){
    case 'home':
        $title = 'bem vindo ao site';
        $content = 'pages/home.php';
        break;
    case 'about':
        $title = 'nosso conteudo';
        $content = 'pages/about.php';
        break;
}
//agora vem o html como o echo no titulo
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title;?></title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- conteúdo da paginação -->
<?php include $content;?>
</body>
</html>
```

O porém dessa técnica é que se o site tiver muitas páginas essa lógica pode ser inviável...

Comment: Boa hugo! eu aprendi essa técnica no estagio que eu fazia, ela é bem comum mesmo e útil

Comment: @JulioHenrique97 eu não trabalho muito com PHP, mas para projetos maiores ela pode não ser a melhor opção, ai o seu podelo pode ser mais interessante. Mas para projetos pequenos essa lógica funciona bem. O que falta é fazer um teste A/B SEO para ver qual o Google rankeia melhor...

Answer (score 2):

ah jovem para resolver seu problema.

o nome da página é prog.php por exemplo, 
primeiro você pega o nome da pagina atual:

```
<?php
echo basename( __FILE__ ) ."\n";

$path_parts = pathinfo( __FILE__ );
 echo '1.'.$path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
 echo '2.'.$path_parts['basename'], "\n";
 echo '3.'.$path_parts['extension'], "\n";
 echo '4.'.$path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // desde o PHP 5.2.0
?>
```

está sequencia irá exibir:

```
prog.php
1./home/eq1okH
2.prog.php
3.php
4.prog
```

Agora você precisa atribuir o nome da página a uma variável e sempre colocar na sua tag `<title>`:

```
$var_title = $path_parts['filename'];

<title><?php echo $var_title; ?>
```

Ai sempre que você mudar de página essa variável vai atualizar e mudar o title e outras coisas que você quiser da sua página.